# How to I create a unit test for a Visual Studio 2015 RC / .NET Core project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I've just started to play around with the new Visual Studio 2015 RC but I've run into a problem in that I can't seem to find an example project that shows how to unit-test the new .NET COre code.  An example or even being pointed in the right direction would be very helpful.  Thanks....

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to unit-test .NET Core itself, or you want to unit test an app written for .NET Core?

Comment: If you check their GitHub repository you can use xUnit.net is used to write unit test cases and you should do the same. BTW, why do you use asp.net tag? This question is not ASP.NET related.

Comment: I removed the ASP.NET flag (thank you Ron).

Comment: I want to unit-test an app written for .NET Core (i.e. my own class library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at [xUnit](http://xunit.github.io/), it was written by the author of nUnit, it's compatible with all of the new vNext goodness (Asp.Net 5, Universal Apps, and Xamirin, CoreClr) and it's what the tests for [MVC vNext](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/test) are written in.  It also works with nCrunch.

You can install it from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice (which I definitely plan to take!)  xUnit aside, though, I still want to perform Intellitests, which for some reason aren't showing up on the pop menu like they should

Comment: If Intellitests are what I think they are (using one test against multiple inputs), I think the xUnit equivalent is a theory, like [this](http://www.tomdupont.net/2012/04/xunit-theory-data-driven-unit-test.html)